# Can't read .avi files using Python OpenCV 4.1.2-dev

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, artificial-intelligence

I wanna run my opencv3.1 programs, but when i try to read a file using **cv2.VideoCapture** shows me the error:

**error: (-5:Bad argument) CAP_IMAGES: can't find starting number (in the name of file): ./../images/walking.avi in function 'icvExtractPattern'**

But, when i using the camera with cv2.VideoCapture(0) it works perfectly. I verify the file path and using the relative and the absolute path, but still not working.

I gonna wait for your answers.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Originally I used `cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')` getting the same error

switch the `(*'XVID') to (*'MJPG')`

I am using a raspberry pi Gen. 4 (4GB) with image: Raspbian Buster Lite

Comment: I'm just trying to get a .avi video into my program using cv2.VideoCapture('video.avi'). But now it shows me: VIDIOC_REQBUFS: Inappropriate ioctl for device. By the way, i'm using ubuntu 18.04